# Is this database normalization correct

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-normalization

I have payments tables with payment/paymentinfo and userinfo ,
I normalized them in the following way:

1NF of payments:

- `Payments(paymentid, courseid, userid, paymentoption, amount, paid date)`

2NF :

- `Paymentsinfo(Paymentid, paymentoption, amount, courseid)`
- `Paidcourseinfo(courseid, courseduration, paymentsid)`
- `Payeeuserinfo(paymentid, userid, courseid)`

Paymentid-PK of payments 
Course Id is a foreign key and a primary key

Comment: Hi. You are not clear. Are you trying to normalize the 1NF to 2NF? Also: Normalization up to BCNF uses FDs to replace a table by others. You haven't mentioned FDs. So we can't help you. Since you haven't given necessary absolutely fundamental info, it doesn't seem like you understand what you are to do or what "normalization (to higher NFs)" means. Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & give your textbook & show your work following it. PS The 1NF does not have courseduration so the 2NF cannot be a normalization of it. (I guess paymentsid is a typo.)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that for every payment paid, the **paymentid** is different, even if its for the same course (*when 2 different students apply for same course*) or when 2 payments by same user(*when same user pays for 2 different courses*).

This means that in **paymentid** is the candidate key and since only one attribute in candidate key, it means no partial functional dependency and hence all your relations are in **2NF**.